# Displaying Django Form Results

Tags: python, django

I have a Django Form (ModelForm) which has a number of fields. When the user presses submit these are then saved to a database. What I am struggling to work out is, how do I then output/render these results in some other HTML page.

Models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Contract(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    doorNo = models.SlugField(max_length=200)
    Address = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

Forms.py

```
from django import forms
from contracts.models import Contract

class GenerateContract(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = Contract
        fields = '__all__'
```

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from contracts.forms import GenerateContract

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'contracts/index.html')

def contractview(request):
    form = GenerateContract()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = GenerateContract(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
            return index(request)
        else:
            print('ERROR')
    return render(request,'contracts/contracts.html',{'form':form})
```

At the moment, I am returning the 'Index' Home page of the app as a placeholder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After validation, the form data is found in `form.cleaned_data` dictionary. So you can pass that back to the template and display it as you see fit.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from contracts.forms import GenerateContract

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'contracts/index.html')

def contractview(request):
    form = GenerateContract()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = GenerateContract(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
            return render(request,'contracts/contracts.html',{'form_data': form.cleaned_data})
        else:
            print('ERROR')
    return render(request,'contracts/contracts.html',{'form':form})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what is the format of the template tag is rendered, e.g. {{ form.data['address'] }} to call back the address field? There is also a syntax error with the response owing to the blank space and extra bracket.

Comment: Should be available in `{{ form_data.address }}`. I am not able to test the code right now.

Comment: Thats perfect and all working now! Thanks you got me out of a mental roadblock

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the form with the saved values, you can render the template with form and fill the instance input . like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from contracts.forms import GenerateContract

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'contracts/index.html')

def contractview(request):
    form = GenerateContract()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = GenerateContract(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            saved_instance = form.save(commit=True)
            return render(request,'contracts/contracts.html',{'form':GenerateContract(instance=saved_instance)})
        else:
            print('ERROR')
    return render(request,'contracts/contracts.html',{'form':form})
```

Comment: Thats's not quite what I am looking for, it needs to render to a different HTML template where the specific field names can be inserted into the template, e.g. This is the {{ name }} and this is the {{ Address }}.

Comment: Well, you don't want the form then! Just pass the instance itself to the template . Then use instance.name and instance.address. in double curly brackets.